# Elasticsearch bulk insertion: documents are created but not created?

Tags: elasticsearch, bulkinsert

I'm inserting 100..1000 docs at a time using bulk insert. Each doc is 100..1500 bytes long, all of them inserted to the same index, same mapping type, `_id` is auto-generated. The data is from log file so I'm pretty sure there were no such docs in the index before.

The insertion returns no errors so I assume the docs were inserted successfully. But when I check number and size of documents in the index (`_cat/indices`) they remains unchanged!

I've checked number of deleted documents but it is very low (less than 5 during that period). Why the docs are not inserted or why there's no error?

Sample od insertion:

```
{ "index" : { "_type" : "default"} }
{"@timestamp":"2017-10-30T06:25:57.597369","@message":{"0":{"file":"\/core\/model\/mysql.php","line":"272","msg":"sql end","query_id":"6967ed6decd5cf9a72f99872b7e38238","duration":"0.038952112197876"},"pid":7700,"i":"i-0d93e","u":"107480"}}
```

Response is like this:

```
Array
(
    [took] => 24
    [errors] =>
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [index] => Array
                        (
                            [_index] => dump_log
                            [_type] => default
                            [_id] => AV9xPp6aE9w_DiFlsbmv
                            [_version] => 1
                            [result] => created
                            [_shards] => Array
                                (
                                    [total] => 2
                                    [successful] => 1
                                    [failed] => 0
                                )

                            [created] => 1
                            [status] => 201
                        )

                )
....
```

Comment: Have you changed the `refresh_interval` for that index?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Yes, I tried 30s and -1 but the result is the same.

Comment: Exactly my point. Have you tried searching the documents after a refresh actually happened? The documents are made available for search after a refresh.

Comment: I initially tried without refresh_interval change. Also, I've set it to 30s 10 hours ago but the amount of docs still the same :(

Comment: What command do you use to check that the documents exist?

Comment: `curl -s https://example.com/_cat/indices?v`

Comment: What do you get if you do `GET /dump_log/_count` ?

Comment: Thank you for your efforts :( `{"count":5193,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0}}` It is two times less than I see with `_cat/indices` and there should be millions

Comment: But you said it didn't add any documents. I thought the count should be 0 or close to it.

Comment: Sometimes when I repeat absolutely the same insert request (arrow up then enter in shell) it works. Also, I can insert data non-bulk way without issues.